# Does the /clone command save NBT dat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been working on a small Minecraft map that uses the `/clone` command to copy command blocks to certain locations and I was wondering, does the `/clone` command save the `NBT` data of command blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.
I tried an experiment in a single-player world with an infinite cloning machine, and it worked there.  Also refer to this [SethBling video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOSSO1WflWE#t=62) with basically the same thing except with a hopper clock.